# Recursive Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, recursion, db2

I found this code snipped ([Source](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/mysql-stored-procedure/0596100892/ch22s07.html)):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rec_fib(n INT, OUT out_fib INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE n_1 INT;
  DECLARE n_2 INT;

  IF (n=0) THEN
    SET out_fib=0;
  ELSEIF (n=1) then
    SET out_fib=1;
  ELSE
    CALL rec_fib(n-1,n_1);
    CALL rec_fib(n-2,n_2);
    SET out_fib=(n_1 + n_2);
  END IF;
END
```

This code works with MySQL. In how far do I have to modify it to run on DB2? I cannot seem to find a running minimal example of an recursive stored procedure for DB2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me: (I haven't done more than make it work, so alternative coding could also work.)

First, add these two lines:

```
DECLARE n_3 INT;
DECLARE n_4 INT;
```

Then modify this small section:

```
ELSE
   set n_3 = n - 1;
   set n_4 = n - 2;
   CALL rec_fib(n_3,n_1);
   CALL rec_fib(n_4,n_2);
```

That's all. Runs on IBM i 6.1 DB2 UDB.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is from SQL tips for DB2, written by Serge Rielau

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Fib(n INTEGER) RETURNS DECIMAL(31, 0)
BEGIN
      DECLARE res DECIMAL(31, 0);
  CASE WHEN n = 0 THEN
             SET res = 0;
       WHEN n = 1 THEN
         SET res = 1;
       WHEN n > 1 THEN
         BEGIN
           DECLARE stmt STATEMENT;
           PREPARE stmt FROM 'SET ? = Fib(? - 1) + Fib(? - 2)';
           EXECUTE stmt INTO res USING n, n;
     END;
       ELSE
         SIGNAL SQLSTATE '78000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Bad input';
  END CASE;
  RETURN res;
END;
/
```

For more information, please check the source page of this code: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/recursive_sql_pl?lang=en